# Geometry offset function is not working correctly

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, geometry, c#, arcgis-runtime

I'm trying to add offset in polygon feature and I'm using Esri a GIS software in C#.

The issue that I'm facing is after I create a polygon and click on functionality for creating offset inside polygon I get,

1. A very large offset that cover more area than my polygon Geometry.
2. No Offset is drawn.

I use 2 feet offset but user can enter more or less.

Here's the snippet of code that I used,

```
 Geometry geom = webMapView.SketchEditor.Geometry;
 Geometry Geom = Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.GeometryEngine.Project(geom, new SpatialReference(4326));               geom = Geom;
 OffSetGeometry = GeometryEngine.Offset(geom, -distance, OffsetType.Round, 1, 1);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could it be that having coordinate reference system EPSG:4326 means that your offset if 2 degrees, that is about 220 km?

Comment: This could be the issue, as the area of offset is way bigger. What do you suggest i should use instead of 4326 ?

Comment: tried 2029, but didn't worked

Comment: Because offset does not seem to support alternative length units then you should give the offset as degrees for EPSG:4326 or convert your data into some foot based coordinate system if you want to use feet as input https://developers.arcgis.com/net/uwp/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_GeometryEngine_Offset.htm

Comment: Thank you for Replying, this might be the problem but i'm not sure how to give offset as degrees or convert data into some foot based coordinate system ?

Comment: You can use a calculator for unit conversion. Either your own or for example http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html.

Comment: Modern releases of ArcGIS are capable of geodesic buffering, though if your 10.1 tag is correct, you're at least six major releases from modern.

Comment: Buffering is working fine, its offset that is giving problem.

Comment: You're projecting to WGS84/DD, change 4326 to the EPSG (factory) code of a suitable projected CRS for the area you're working in then project OffSetGeometry to EPSG:4326 if that's what is desired.